# Navigation2 - Goal Status message in ROS2 humble

Tags: navigation, ros2, ros-humble

I am using the ROS2 Humble Navigation2 package and want to check if the robot reached the goal position (or it reached the xy_goal_tolerance zone).

I know there is a [GoalStatus message in ROS2 foxy](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/action_msgs/msg/GoalStatus.html) but I cannot find its corresponding version in ROS2 humble.

Is there a way to use a similar message in Ros2 humble?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its all the same for all ROS 2 distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see it with

```
$ cat /opt/ros/humble/share/action_msgs/msg/GoalStatus.msg
```